# How do i fetch data from a one worksheet to another to calculate total working hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet

I have 2 worksheet, one is a automobile floor tracking sheet where there are columns like total allotted time and total time taken by each technicians, the other is an efficiency sheet where I wanted to track each technicians efficiency. how do I do it.?

Floor tracking sheet

[image]

Efficiency tracking sheet

[image]

I tried sumifs and I couldn't get exact values I was trying to get

here is the expected results [Floor tracking sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNNOD.jpg),[Efficiency tracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ixij.jpg)

Comment: You have two columns of technicians. Could you explain in more detail how this should work? Also, add some sample data and a screenshot of the expected result. Don't forget to add the formula(s) you have tried.

Comment: Basically, the first sheet is the main sheet where the workshop floor is managed. you see 2 columns of technician because in some cases 2 technicians work on the same job and the total time alloted for the job should be halved for each, like if a service takes 1hr for 2 technicians to complete then each technician get 30mins to complete it and their efficiency is calculated to be according the half of total time taken to complete the job.where as in the second sheet i need the total alloted time for each technician and and the total time taken by them which should be fetched from the mainsheet

Comment: perhaps a bit more specifity in the Q - to leave less 'thinking/understanding' to those of us who might be able to assist - e.g. are you looking to sum totals from sheet 1 into sheet 2 ? are you looking to apply some kind of formula or KPI to measure efficiency (which in itelf is quite broad and without universal/singular definition) - or must I open up the small screenshot to make sense of all of this?  e.g. perhaps Q should be rephrased like so "How do I sum col B by unique values based on col A"? (and give a pivot table a go in the first instance - that might solve your issue to begin with)